# Permanent storage container with electrode for electroplating

Tags: equipment, electroplating

I'm not a chemist at all but I am looking for a specific type of container which I'm sure must exist but I don't know it's name.

We want to store non-toxic (non-cyanide) gold solution for electroplating in a small (10-20ml) transparent container that has an inbuilt, permanent electrode for the plating process:

[image: figure showing container setup]

But I can't find anywhere to buy such a thing and I don't know if it has a specific name. The electrode would have to be made of a material which will not react with the gold solution, so as not to contaminate it.

Why do we want this specific setup? We want to gold plate fine wires which are inserted into the solution from the top of the container, these are fragile and expensive which is why I would rather avoid having a temporary electrode inserted into the solution each time. We have a small amount of gold solution at a time and it is expensive so I would rather store the solution in the plating container permanently. The container really needs to be transparent so we can see that the plating wires are in the solution.

Any help would be massively appreciated,

Thanks,

M.